# Calculate position on Isometric grid

Tags: unity, mathematics, isometric, coordinates, grid

I created the following tile grid in unity3d:
The blue dot is the  absolute center point (0,0) of both scene space and tile map.

[image]

Now I am trying to calculate the X/Y position of points on the tile map ( the black coordinates). The red coordinates are positions in the scene space. Every calculation I make just gives me a wrong result. Is the tile map roatated the wrong way? Any help really apreciated!

Comment: Have you considered to have your map orthogonal in scene-space and then just give the camera a diagonal rotation? That should make a lot of things much simpler.

Comment: Thas is a genius idea! Thanks very much! Unfortunately I coded the whole level editor already so I'm gonna stick to that for a while I guess. But I think that could have safed me some time :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
tileExtents = new Vector2(0.3f, 0.17f);

scenePos.x = tileExtents.x * (tilePos.x - tilePos.y);
scenePos.y = tileExtents.y * (tilePos.x + tilePos.y);
```

so we can solve these equations to get the result:

```
scenePos.x/tileExtents.x = tilePos.x - tilePos.y
scenePos.y/tileExtents.y = tilePos.x + tilePos.y
```

adding the two to get x:

```
scenePos.x/tileExtents.x + scenePos.y/tileExtents.y = 2 * tilePos.x

tilePos.x = (scenePos.x/tileExtents.x + scenePos.y/tileExtents.y) * 0.5f;
```

subtracting the two to get y:

```
scenePos.x/tileExtents.x - scenePos.y/tileExtents.y = -2 * tilePos.y

tilePos.y = (scenePos.y/tileExtents.y - scenePos.x/tileExtents.x) * 0.5f
```